# R data.table slow aggregation when using .SD

Tags: r, data.table

I'm doing some aggregations on a data.table (excellent package!!!) and I found the .SD variable very useful for many things. However, using it slows down computation significantly when there are many groups. Follows an example:

```
# A moderately big data.table
x = data.table(id=sample(1e4,1e5,replace=T),
               code=factor(sample(2,1e5,replace=T)),
               z=runif(1e5)
              )

setkey(x,id,code)

system.time(x[,list(code2=nrow(.SD[code==2]), total=.N), by=id])
##  user  system elapsed 
##  6.226   0.000   6.242

system.time(x[,list(code2=sum(code==2), total=.N), by=id])
## user  system elapsed 
## 0.497   0.000   0.498

system.time(x[,list(code2=.SD[code==2,.N], total=.N), by=id])
## user  system elapsed 
## 6.152   0.000   6.168
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I avoid .SD in favor of individual columns? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong i.e. should I avoid `.SD` in favor of individual columns ?

Yes, exactly.  Only use `.SD` if you really are using all the data inside `.SD`. You might also find that the call to `nrow()` and the subquery call to `[.data.table` inside `j` are culprits too : use `Rprof` to confirm.

See the last few sentences of [FAQ 2.1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#how-can-i-avoid-writing-a-really-long-j-expression-youve-said-that-i-should-use-the-column-names-but-ive-got-a-lot-of-columns.) :

> *FAQ 2.1 How can I avoid writing a really long j expression? You've said I should use the column names, but I've got a lot of columns.*
>   When grouping, the `j` expression can use column names as variables, as
>   you know, but it can also use a reserved symbol `.SD` which refers to
>   the Subset of the Data.table for each group (excluding the grouping
>   columns). So to sum up all your columns it's just
>   `DT[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=grp]`. It might seem tricky, but it's fast to
>   write and fast to run. Notice you don't have to create an anonymous
>   function. See the timing vignette and wiki for comparison to other
>   methods. The `.SD` object is efficiently implemented internally and more
>   ecient than passing an argument to a function. **Please don't do this
>   though : `DT[,sum(.SD[,"sales",with=FALSE]),by=grp]`. That works but is very
>   inefficient and inelegant. This is what was intended:
>   `DT[,sum(sales),by=grp]` and could be 100's of times faster.**

Also see the first bullet of FAQ 3.1 :

> *FAQ 3.1 I have 20 columns and a large number of rows. Why is an expression of one column so quick?* 
>   Several reasons: 
>    --  Only that column is
>   grouped, the other 19 are ignored because `data.table` inspects the `j`
>   expression and realises it doesn't use the other columns.

When `data.table` inspects `j` and sees the `.SD` symbol, that efficiency gain goes out the window. It will have to populate the whole of the `.SD` subset for each group even if you don't use all its columns. It's very difficult for `data.table` to know which columns of `.SD` you are really using (`j` could contain `if`s, for example). However, if you need them all anyway, it doesn't matter of course, such as in `DT[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=...]`. That's ideal use of `.SD`.

So, yes, avoid `.SD` wherever possible.  Use column names directly to give data.table's optimization of `j` the best chance.  The mere existence of the symbol `.SD` in `j` is important.

This is why `.SDcols` was introduced. So you can tell `data.table` which columns should be in `.SD` if you only want a subset.  Otherwise, `data.table` will populate `.SD` with all the columns just in case `j` needs them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was tricked by the phrase "The .SD object is efficiently implemented internally and more efficient than passing an argument to a function" and did not understand the "Please don't do this though : DT[,sum(.SD[,"sales",with=FALSE]),by=grp]" due to the with=FALSE. This will speedup a lot my code!

Comment: @vsalmendra Ah, yes it could be clearer. It's the sort of thing that's been left to community discussion in the past. Ultimately we're hoping to improve `j` optimization so that users don't need to know things like this.

Comment: @vsalmendra I've now improved FAQ 2.1 for the next release.

Answer (score 4):

Try solving this by breaking the calculations into two steps, then merging the resulting data frames:

```
system.time({
  x2 <- x[code==2, list(code2=.N), by=id]
  xt <- x[, list(total=.N), by=id]
  print(x2[xt])
})
```

On my machine it runs in 0.04 seconds as opposed to 7.42 seconds, i.e. ~200 times faster than your original code:

```
         id code2 total
   1:     1     6    14
   2:     2     8    10
   3:     3     7    13
   4:     4     5    13
   5:     5     9    18
  ---                  
9995:  9996     4     9
9996:  9997     3     6
9997:  9998     6    10
9998:  9999     3     4
9999: 10000     3     6
   user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.00    0.04
```

Comment: (+1) I'd replace `x2` with `x2 <- x[J(unique(id), "2"), list(code2 = .N)][, code := NULL, keyby="id"]`. Your code removes rows where code != 2 for a given id.

Comment: +1 Actually that is a lot faster than `x[,list(sum(code==2),.N),by=id]` (example 2 in question) isn't it! Maybe because you're avoiding the repeated call to `==` for each group (associated allocation etc for those small vectors).

Comment: @Arun Are you sure?  `x2[xt][is.na(code2)]` has some rows. You just get `NA` instead of `0`. Might be wrong, only looked quickly.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, No, I just meant at the step of `x2`. `x2` has 9921 rows instead of 9999. Of course at the end, with x[y], those rows get an NA. I thought indexing with `J(key columns)` should be faster than `logical indexing`... Did I get it wrong?

Comment: @Arun A single vector scan on a single column is a special case: the `unique(id)` call has to scan every item too anyway, then plus the time to join.  Just to check, it's not a problem that `x2` has 9921 rows instead of 9999 rows then? (That's what your comment above seemed to suggest that it was).

Comment: Yes, it is not a problem as the x[y] at a later stage rectifies this. I should have mentioned that the reason was rather for "speed", but it seems not the case. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Great. New feature request [FR#2597](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=978&func=detail&aid=2597) filed to see if we can build this technique into data.table.